# How are Cookies managed by the browser

Tags: java, tomcat, cookies, browser

I am a trying to understant how does browser which cookies to incluse: suppose i have 2 web applications deployed under the same  server,every  application has its jsessionid,how will the browser include the  correct cookie.
If it use the application context,how does it get the context values?
Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Domain_and_Path, and you can also view the cookies in your browser if you'd like to check it out on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes browser uses application context which is a root context of URL. i.e.

```
Request URL1: http://myhost.com/myApp1/index.jsp
Response Set-Cookie Header: Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=abcd...; path=/myApp1
```

Browser keeps it as cookie for myhost.com for path /myApp1 as Server sent it.

```
Request URL2: http://myhost.com/myApp2/index.jsp
Response Set-Cookie Header: Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=edf...; path=/myApp2
```

Browser keeps it as cookie for myhost.com for path /myApp2 as Server sent it.

Actually it depeneds only on Server. Whatever Server sends in path browser will keep it for that resource. i.e. if path from server will be `/myApp1/resource1` then browser sends that cookie only with request to that URL context

Comment: Thanks Vadim for thé confirmation

Comment: you are welcome